# Hibernate 1 to M restriction on children

Tags: java, sql, hibernate

I have 1 to M association with Country and Person. Meaning a Country can have multiple persons. The country.hbm.xml fils is shown below:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-mapping PUBLIC
    "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Mapping DTD 3.0//EN"
    "http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-mapping-3.0.dtd">
<hibernate-mapping package="com.test.hibernate">
  <class name="Country">
  <id name="countryId" column="CountryID" > </id>
  <property name="countryName" column="CountryName" length="50"></property>
  <set name="persons" table="Person" fetch="select" inverse="true">
  <key>
    <column name="CountryId" not-null="true"></column>
  </key> 
   <one-to-many class="com.test.hibernate.Person"/>     
  </set>
  </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

The Person.hbm.xml is shown below

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-mapping PUBLIC
    "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Mapping DTD 3.0//EN"
    "http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-mapping-3.0.dtd">
<hibernate-mapping package="com.test.hibernate">
  <class name="Person">
    <id name="personID" column="PersonID" > </id>
    <property name="name" column="Name" length="50"></property>
    <property name="age" column="Age"></property>
    <property name="gender" column="Gender" length="1"></property>
    <property name="email" column="Email" length="50"></property>
    <property name="countryID" column="CountryID" insert="false" update="false"></property>

    <many-to-one name="Country" class="com.test.hibernate.Country" fetch="select">
        <column name="CountryID" not-null="true"></column>
    </many-to-one> 
  </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

Now, I am trying to query all the persons who are males belonging to India Country

```
Criteria countryCriteria = session.createCriteria(Country.class);
Criterion country = Restrictions.eq("countryName", "India");
Criterion male = Restrictions.eq("persons.gender", "M");
countryCriteria.add(country);
countryCriteria.add(male);
List<Country> countryList = countryCriteria.list();
```

I am getting a 
Exception in thread "main" org.hibernate.QueryException: could not resolve property: persons.gender of: com.test.hibernate.Country
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractPropertyMapping.propertyException(AbstractPropertyMapping.java:83)
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractPropertyMapping.toColumns(AbstractPropertyMapping.java:98)
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.BasicEntityPropertyMapping.toColumns(BasicEntityPropertyMapping.java:61)
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.toColumns(AbstractEntityPersister.java:1960)
    at org.hibernate.loader.criteria.CriteriaQueryTranslator.getColumns(CriteriaQueryTranslator.java:523)
    at org.hibernate.loader.criteria.CriteriaQueryTranslator.findColumns(CriteriaQueryTranslator.java:538)
    at org.hibernate.criterion.SimpleExpression.toSqlString(SimpleExpression.java:66)
    at org.hibernate.loader.criteria.CriteriaQueryTranslator.getWhereCondition(CriteriaQueryTranslator.java:419)
    at org.hibernate.loader.criteria.CriteriaJoinWalker.(CriteriaJoinWalker.java:123)
    at org.hibernate.loader.criteria.CriteriaJoinWalker.(CriteriaJoinWalker.java:92)
    at org.hibernate.loader.criteria.CriteriaLoader.(CriteriaLoader.java:95)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.list(SessionImpl.java:1643)
    at org.hibernate.internal.CriteriaImpl.list(CriteriaImpl.java:374)
    at com.test.hibernate.Main.main(Main.java:54)

Please help. I am new to Hibernate.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used M to 1 and used Criteria on Person object as opposed to Country Object.

```
Criteria personCriteria = session.createCriteria(Person.class,"p");
personCriteria.createAlias("p.Country", "c");    
Criterion gender = Restrictions.eq("gender", "M");
Criterion country = Restrictions.eq("c.countryName", "India");
personCriteria.add(gender);
personCriteria.add(country);
List<Person> personList = personCriteria.list();
```

This way the personList had all the Persons who were males and belonged to India.

Answer (score 2):

`Country.persons`is of type `Collection<Person>`. A Collection doesn't have any property named "gender".

If you used HQL instead of Criteria (and you should, for such a simple static query), you would have to do a join:

```
select c from Country c 
join country.persons person
where c.countryName = 'India' 
and person.gender = 'M'
```

You thus have to do the same with the Criteria query:

```
Criteria countryCriteria = session.createCriteria(Country.class, "c");
countryCriteria.createALias("c.persons", "person");
countryCriteria.add(Restrictions.eq("c.countryName", "India"));
countryCriteria.add(Restrictions.eq("person.gender", "M"));
List<Country> countryList = countryCriteria.list();
```

Comment: If I change my code to your suggestions, its returning me 3 elements in the countryList, each element has all the 3 persons belonging to India of both genders (M And F). The query seems to be applied only on the country level and not on the person level

Comment: With HQL, use `select distinct c ...`. With Criteria, use `countryCriteria.setResultTransformer(Criteria.DISTINCT_ROOT_ENTITY)`

Comment: I added Distinct root entity to the countrycriteria variable. Now, I just see 1 root element. But the children in the root element still have unfiltered records. Meaning both genders (M and F) are still present. The query spec is applied only on the root level.

Comment: That's completely expected. If you want only some persons, you have to query persons, not countries. A country's persons contains the country's persons, all of them.

Comment: I am trying to query on both person and Country table. My SQL query would be SELECT C.*, P.* FROM COUNTRY C INNER JOIN PERSON P ON P.COUNTRYID = C.COUNTRYID WHERE C.COUNTRYNAME = 'INDIA' AND P.GENDER = 'M'. Should I use M to 1 association in this case where I use the Person entity?

Comment: You can do the same and use `select c, person from ...` or just `select person from ...`. Just don't expect a country's persons not to contain all the country's persons.